# To add model and access database in Booktype

Tags: python, django, sqlite, booktype

I am trying to access the database in Booktype. I am using sqlite3. I am not able to view the tables. And even don't know how to create a new model.

How do I access and add model to the booktype?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `sqliteman` to view your sqlite3 database

you should learn basic django docs, models

when run `python manage.py syncdb`, django will create tables in database (configuration in settings.py)